# GoJS different ResizingTool for Groups and Nodes

Tags: javascript, gojs

Is it possible to use a different `ResizingTool` for different node templates?
In my case I have a group containing some notes and I want to resize the groups with a custom `ResizingTool` and the nodes inside the group should use the default `ResizingTool`.

As far as I can see the `resizingTool` property can only be set at the diagram itself, so the same tool for everything!?

A hotfix I'm using now is to call the original `go.ResizingTool` functions in my custom tool depending on a node type condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is one correct approach -- have each override look at the http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/ResizingTool.html#adornedObject and decide what to do.

A similar approach would be to have instances of two different **ResizingTool**s, both the standard one and your custom one, installed as **ToolManager.mouseDownTools**.  You would install your custom, more specific, tool just before the **ToolManager.resizingTool** in that **ToolManager.mouseDownTools** list, *and* you would need to override **ResizingTool.canStart** so that it would return true only when it's OK *and* the resize handle is on one of your groups.

Something like:

```
GroupResizingTool.prototype.canStart = function() {
  if (!this.isEnabled) return false;
  var diagram = this.diagram;
  if (diagram === null || diagram.isReadOnly) return false;
  if (!diagram.allowResize) return false;
  if (!diagram.lastInput.left) return false;

  var h = this.findToolHandleAt(diagram.firstInput.documentPoint, this.name);
  return (h !== null && h.part.adornedPart instanceof go.Group);
}
```

Or maybe your final predicate would check that the adorned Part is of a particular category.  Or any other needed discrimination.

When your custom **canStart** fails, then the next tool would be the standard **ResizingTool**, which would operate normally but only on those nodes for which your custom tool did not.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, currently I'm using something like this in all overides (only 2 so thats ok I guess): `if (!(this.adornedObject.part instanceof go.Group)) go.ResizingTool.prototype.resize.call(this, newr);`. But the tip with the `ToolManager.mouseDownTools` is great, especially if one needs even more the two `ResizingTools`.